# How do I implement caching?

Tags: webkit

I have created a browser for yourself based on the [MiniBrowser].

```
Use     :Webkit
Platform: Windows7 64bit
Tool    : VisualStudio2005
```

The trouble is that I have several have produced.

1. I want to increase the cache size.
2. I want to cache the page.
3. I want to keep the link to read.

Please let me know which function is needed to fulfill them.

Comment: Not getting what you have asked

Comment: I think you need some real time libraries for this which should keep data in memory